# How should I use webclient for oauth 2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I handled a lot of API from many exchanges.

I want the API to work without user intervention.

Usually, I wrote codes like this

```
Dim timestamp = getEstimatedServerTimeStamp().ToString
Dim domain = "https://api.kucoin.com"
Dim endpoint = "/api/v1/" + method
Dim stringtosign = timestamp + "GET" + endpoint '1553106384182GET/api/v1/accounts
'Dim secretandpassphrase = _secret1.Split("|"c)
'Dim secret = secretandpassphrase(0) 'a7c38ae4-b6e3-4254-b78c-*******
'Dim passphrase = secretandpassphrase(1) '7Q5eVqOw*******

Dim hasher = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secret1))
Dim sighashbyte = hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringtosign))
Dim sighash = System.Convert.ToBase64String(sighashbyte)
Dim url = domain + endpoint 'url https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts
Dim response = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1(url, "", {Tuple.Create("KC-API-SIGN", sighash), Tuple.Create("KC-API-TIMESTAMP", timestamp), Tuple.Create("KC-API-KEY", _apiKey1), Tuple.Create("KC-API-PASSPHRASE", _passphrase1)})

Return response
```

So I am using the secret and the API key.

However, at Sstex, something is different.

First, they told me to register a client and a redirect URL. What does redirect URL mean?

I tried

going to https://apidocs.stex.com/#/Profile/get_profile_wallets

to try some demo.

It turns out I can see my wallet content without using my API key and secret at all. Instead of API key and secret I authorize here

https://apidocs.stex.com/#/Profile/get_profile_wallets

Then I can see my balances.

So I tried some similar code after looking on the web

I did

```
   If token = "" Then
        Dim token1 = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("https://app.stex.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1**&client_secret=3vmEisPCGekF1JGePkwdSKdf4Q00lJTKmwxh****")

    End If
```

Instead of json I am getting an html.

So I wonder.

What exactly I should do with OAuth? Is it designed for something different than regular API access?

The manual says I should curl things like

```
curl -X GET "https://api3.stex.com/profile/wallets?sort=DESC&sortBy=BALANCE" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjY1NzUyODQwYmMzMmMwNGU0MTExNmRmYjQ0M2I5NWY4NzAzYmVkYWIyNTk0ZWZhMTg3ZjhhMmQxOThiNzM1NGRkNThjZmYzYWJkZWEzZjg5In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxNDIiLCJqdGkiOiI2NTc1Mjg0MGJjMzJjMDRlNDExMTZkZmI0NDNiOTVmODcwM2JlZGFiMjU5NGVmYTE4N2Y4YTJkMTk4YjczNTRkZDU4Y2ZmM2FiZGVhM2Y4OSIsImlhdCI6MTU1MzI4NTc4NiwibmJmIjoxNTUzMjg1Nzg2LCJleHAiOjE1NTMzMjg5ODYsInN1YiI6IjMxOTgwMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJwcm9maWxlIiwicmVwb3J0cyIsInRyYWRlIl19.aRuu1gmUmpcck_rMh9fcQwfDeJezn0tD0v1aSJ7joIhtsIXAdaw0H-SFOXwzo_HevFrcDnWGrZ4s9sTd1_vgRS2or7HyiV54c0ItVym6bOMKnFhGuxWWLubXN9HstjiM9TSghk7FtF5J0XeIDcY4vp25ycBmWM6Dddeyu4ehu3hurG-jUyT9N1C4u5KwqkYazeE1Z6XpCUrH77tAIlecTssPUzDtM6j-dYJOirYLx-E7fTn6H_bpHq_mosiHEy7IGe2uyggx0UIg4YIIX0noATxNfFiqZlXc32u8NywS7bDkFJ8e4s2r6vbL9pZU7Qe81IFrhs2jgUrQyjxe4SKsyolA9SulwF1haqsRGYTN_fNZyNm7u_Nzs2-RWxZw7h5KHT48AI483bHqJS3qfpjNF7FdpEufnn1QuFplumvyATtlEf56RCTfZ11fWjaET_b19P_3KpJw8H3pYSh8f-7MdIJcn68X1ls_9GahKKlX059I2M_6S2XkjwvnETlhiWGIdpttg2rJ1oHsEiNUuYzj7d1MBKGhSMX4y8OpB9hhW6CjgajG-YVk3SU6JWaVBEY_1w49Q6U-KxD4nzMK5I85Cn1C1iDPExuOwuyRRH1XSxsXLQ9tURsLOytlp7LkUNvzxb5lxZ18ho-OkvkWVkS18oSxR5y__WllywD_6_NT64s"
```

So I should get a bearer token. How do I get it with say, curl?

I want standard web query such as using curl. I want to avoid unfamiliar library like some specialized oauth library.

I am making an app. I am not making a website. Should I even use oauth2?

I read about oauth2 here

https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#roles

It says that "users" will see some website and they can "authorize".

Look. The user is me. I got the API key, secret, client id, client secret. I don't want "users" to be shown anything. I approve all this stuff.

Stex says that they will abandon their version 2 API and will use version 3API. They said that version 3 API uses Oauth.

Is oauth even suitable for an app that run unattended?